# Access denied error in Tomcat 8 on Windows 7

Tags: tomcat

I am using Tomcat 8 on Windows 7 Ultimate platform. I've deployed an application stored in folder named "feedback". I have simply copied this folder in "webapps" directory of Tomcat.
I can see the application running without any problem. 
But when I try to edit and then save any of the file in "feedback" directory. I get "Access denied to " error.